# dynamically resize div on adding input boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to expand the height of the box in the demo. When I click the '+' button, a new row with two input boxes is created. I used `element.offsetHeight` property to increment the current height by a certain quantity. But since this returns a value in `pixels` and not `em` the resizing is not working as expected. After a certain number of attempts at clicking it, the '+' sign is no longer contained within the `div`.

Here's my attempt:

```js
function addItemPrice() {
    toAppendId = document.getElementById("personExtras0");
    var newItemPrice = document.createElement("div");
    newItemPrice.className = "row";
    newItemPrice.innerHTML = "\
        <div class=\"row\">\
            <div class=\"col-sm-4\">"+
                "<input type=\"text\" name=\"item-name0\" class=\"form-control item-name\" id=\"item-name0\" placeholder=\"Item name\" />"
            +"</div>"+
            "<div class=\"col-sm-4\">"
                +"<input type=\"text\" name=\"item-cost0\" class=\"form-control item-cost\" id=\"item-cost0\" placeholder=\"Item Cost\" />"
            +"</div>"
            "<div class=\"col-sm-4\">"+
                "<i class=\"fa fa-minus fa-2x minus\"></i>"+
            +"</div>\
        </div>";
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("col")[0];
    var height = element.offsetHeight;
    // alert(height);
    var newHeight = height + 40;
    element.style.height = newHeight + "px";
    toAppendId.appendChild(newItemPrice);
}
```

```css
header {
    text-align: center;
}

.add-users-section {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 15em;
}

.add-users-section>.row>.col {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 38%;
    margin-top: 2em;
    background-color: rgb(223, 219, 219);
}

#add-users-section-form {
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

#getNumberOfUsers {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    height: 4em;
    width: 5em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-right: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

#add-users-section-form>button {
    border-radius: 0;
}

#nameOfBill {
    width: 15em;
    height: 2em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}


/* User items consumed section */

.user-items-consumed-section {
    margin-top: 5em;
    margin-left: 10em;
}

.col {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    height: 20em;
    width: 5em;
}

form>.row {
    margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.form-group {
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.item-name {
    margin-left: 0em;
}

.person-name {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.plus {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 0em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.plus:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

.minus {
    margin-top: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.personExtras {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.personExtras>.row {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Input Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ibarra+Real+Nova&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8cf2963f4e.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="users-input-details.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="page-header">
            <h1>Bill Split</h1>
        </header>
        
        <div class="user-items-consumed-section">
            <div class="container">
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col form-group" id="person0">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="person-name" class="form-control person-name border-0" id="person-name0" placeholder="User 1"><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" name="item-name0" class="form-control item-name" id="item-name0" placeholder="Item name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                                    <input type="text" name="item-cost0" class="form-control item-cost" id="item-cost0" placeholder="Item Cost">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                   <i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x minus"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="personExtras0" class="personExtras"></div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 plus" onclick="addItemPrice()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col">
                            <p> Hello </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

The demo works properly only on a full-screen desktop. Apologies. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Emiel's answer is really nice and clean. I tried to adapt your code to show the right direction to go in (jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/1pwe632v/29) but Emiel's answer is far more complete and follows very good style etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no need to set the height manually as the *box* should stretch the size of it's children, if your CSS is set properly. I've tried to fix what was causing your issue, but I'm sorry, it is too much work.

So I've tried to recreate a simplified version which demonstrates that you **don't** need to set the height but should let the document flow and CSS do it's work.

Also I've noticed that you use a lot of `id`'s in your HTML, also when adding new elements. `id`'s have to be unique, otherwise they have no purpose and are practically useless. Consider using `class` instead if you have reoccuring elements with the same styles.

If you have multiple `input` elements with the same `name` attribute in your form, make sure to append `[]` after the value of the name. For example: `name="firstname"` should be `name="firstname[]"`. This enables your form to create groups of values. Otherwise the `firstname` value would be overwritten for each `input` with that name in your form.

Beware of your Bootstrap layout. `col` classes should be placed directly into a `row` and a `row` should only have `col` classes as direct children. If you use `col-sm-6` and within that col another `col-sm-6`, you'll get the width of a `col-sm-3` as result. This will make your layout difficult to work with. Try to use the classes only when necessary of creating columns.

Prevent overwriting CSS of Bootstrap or modifying classes of Bootstrap **directly**. This will create unexpected behavior in your project, like columns that don't size properly.
Instead use *modifier classes* that enhance the CSS on an element but do not overwrite the default CSS of Bootstrap. Or make a new `div` or whatever you need and write your own CSS for it without affecting existing styles.

I understand that you are still learning and I mean everything here above in a constructive sense. Keep it up and keep practicing. You'll do great!

I hope that any of this makes sense and is of any help.
Please let me know, if I've been unclear or didn't properly help you in any way.

Cheers!

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const items = form.querySelector('.items');

const createGroup = () => `
  <div class="group">
    <label>
      <span>Item</span>
      <input type="text" name="item[]">
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Price</span>
      <input type="text" name="price[]">
    </label>
  </div>
`;

form.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const button = event.target.closest('.add');
  if (button !== null) {
    const group = createGroup();
    items.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', group);
  }
});
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.form {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
}

.items {
  counter-reset: groupCount;
}

.group {
  counter-increment: groupCount;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

label span::after {
  content: " " counter(groupCount);
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  margin: 1em 0;
}

button {
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="group">
      <label>
        <span>Item</span>
        <input type="text" name="item[]">
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Price</span>
        <input type="text" name="price[]">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="add" type="button" name="add">Add group</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer is really nice and clean Emiel! I tried to adapt the OP's code to show the right direction to go in (https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/1pwe632v/29/) but you gave the better answer as the OP can learn more from yours :) So I will not post mine.

Comment: @Emiel Thanks a lot! Your answer is really helpful. You’ve pointed me in the right direction as well as commented on some of the ugly practices in what I’ve written with a lot of patience.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier In adding the event listener, couldn't you have created an event listener on the button itself and not the form. Is there a difference? Also, correct me if I'm wrong but, `const button = const button = event.target.closest('.add');` finds if the button is clicked right?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Listening for the click on the butten would have been the same. It's a way of approach between using event delegation and an eventlistener per element. And yes, `Element.closest()` checks if the query set matches an element up in the DOMTree and returns it if it's true. It's a trick to check if there has been a click inside the target element or the target itself has been clicked. It will return `null` if the button is not the clicked target.